# How to use Alamofire to send bytes?

Tags: ios, rest, swift, post, alamofire

I'm creating an application to download my university timetable. I've done the REST calls in Java first to demonstrate a prototype which works nicely. And now I'd like to do it in Swift using Alamofire (or anything else which works).

Below is the REST call in Java that I'm trying to replicate.

```
Client client = Client.create();

String authString = "UID=XXXXX&PASS=XXXXX";
byte[] authBytes = authString.getBytes();

WebResource webResouce = client.resource("https://access.adelaide.edu.au/sa/login.asp");

ClientResponse response = webResource.post(ClientResponse.class, authBytes);

if (response.getStatus != 302) {
throw new RuntimeException("Failed: HTTP code: " + response.getStatus());
}
```

However I'm having trouble sending the bytes properly. The server will actually accept any byte data (so you can see if it works without a UID or PASS) and respond with 302, which indicates that it works. Otherwise it'll send a 200 which means it didn't.

I've had a few attempts of sending the UID and PASS in a parameter, getting their bytes and then putting them in a parameter etc etc. but nothing seems to work so far.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: HTTP status code 200 is OK and 302 is some redirection, so your handling of the status codes looks a bit unusual.

Comment: It's how the server works, I want the 302, not the 200 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Alamofire's custom encoding technique (something like this). This is my 3rd hour of Swift so bear with me.

```
struct ByteEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
  private let data: Data

  init(data: Data) {
    self.data = data
  }

  func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
    var urlRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()
    urlRequest.httpBody = data
    return urlRequest
  }
}

Alamofire.request(url: "url", method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: ByteEncoding(data: authBytesAsData)
```

Documentation
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#custom-encoding

Comment: I really liked this solution, it worked great for me and was super clean

Answer (score 0):

If you use a regular NSURLRequest you can just set the request body:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://access.adelaide.edu.au/sa/login.asp")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
request.HTTPBody = // NSData you want as your body
```

**Edit**

As pointed out by @mattt himself, you can pass an NSURLRequest to Alamofire. No need for the hassle with custom parameter encoding as I answered first. (See below)

---

I don't exactly know how to do this using Alamofire, but it seems you can use a `Custom` parameter encoding with a closure. I didn't test this but took it from the Alamofire unit test source:

```
let encodingClosure: (URLRequestConvertible, [String: AnyObject]?) -> (NSURLRequest, NSError?) = { (URLRequest, parameters) in
    let mutableURLRequest = URLRequest.URLRequest.mutableCopy() as NSMutableURLRequest
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = parameters["data"]
    return (mutableURLRequest, nil)
}

let encoding: ParameterEncoding = .Custom(encodingClosure)

let URL = NSURL(string: "https://access.adelaide.edu.au/sa/login.asp")!
let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL)
let data: NSData = // NSData you want as your body
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = ["data": data]

let URLRequestWithBody = encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work when trying to use Alamofire. With the regular NSURLRequest that you posted first, how would you send the request and then print out the response to check if it had worked? I can't find how to do this simple thing in Swift any where.

Comment: Check out `NSURLSession`: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html, or this handy cookbook: http://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession

Comment: You can pass an `NSURLRequest` directly into an `Alamofire.request(_:)`.

Comment: Ah very nice, that surely simplifies things!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of how you could make this type of request.

```
import Alamofire

class BytesUploader {
    func uploadBytes() {
        let URLRequest: NSURLRequest = {
            let URL = NSURL(string: "https://access.adelaide.edu.au/sa/login.asp")!
            let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
            mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

            let authString = "UID=XXXXX&PASS=XXXXX"
            let authData = authString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
            mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = authData

            return mutableURLRequest.copy() as NSURLRequest
        }()

        let request = Alamofire.request(URLRequest)
        request.response { request, response, data, error in
            if let response = response {
                println("Response status code: \(response.statusCode)")

                if response.statusCode == 302 {
                    println("Request was successful")
                } else {
                    println("Request was NOT successful")
                }
            } else {
                println("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to encode your authorization string as an `NSData` object and then set that as the `HTTPBody` of the `NSURLRequest`. This should match your Java code that you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it also doesn't work. Have you tested it? I still receive the 200 code on my end.

Comment: You could try to comment out setting the `HTTPBody` and see if that gives you a `302`. I just re-read your entire question to make sure I followed everything properly and it looks as though I did. I'm not really interested in debugging you server issues. I really question how this service is set up because it doesn't follow any common conventions. I think a good way to proceed would be to run `debugPrintln(request)` and start comparing the actual cURL between Java and Swift.

Comment: That's ok, thanks for your effort. I wish REST was as straight forward in Swift as it can be in Java. What I'll do now is inspect the http traffic between my iPhone and the server through my universitys timetable app using this tutorial http://jerodsanto.net/2009/06/sniff-your-iphones-network-traffic/. It's a very poor app, that's why I want to remake it, but at least it knows how to get the timetable which I'm struggling with! The REST calls I've been trying to mimic so far have been from the browser. Maybe there's an easier service the app is using.